# Como faço para me conectar em outra rede com socket?

Tags: socket, conexão, redes, ip

Eu já criei alguns programas como um jogo de ping pong multiplayer, chat e outros, utilizando `socket`. Todos eles funcionam perfeitamente e eu consigo me conectar em outros dispositivos que estejam conectados na mesma rede que eu, porém em todos eles, eu não consigo me conectar numa rede diferente.

Eu vou deixar [aqui](https://github.com/JeanExtreme002/File-Transfer) o link para o repositório de um programa que criei recentemente.

Eu pesquisei a fundo, e descobri primeiro que existem dois tipos de ip (privado e público). Antigamente eu não conseguia me conectar, provavelmente porque eu tentava usar um ip privado. Então aqui está a minha primeira pergunta... Como faço para criar o servidor com [esse](https://github.com/JeanExtreme002/File-Transfer) meu programa utilizando ip público ? Eu já tentei usar o ip público e o que eu tinha feito antes foi o seguinte:

1 - Obtive meu IP Público

2 - Abri a *"Central de Rede e Compartilhamento"* > *"Alterar configurações do adaptador"*

3 - Selecionei a rede, cliquei em *"propriedade"* e selecionei *"protocolo TCP/IP versão 4"*

4 - Marquei a opção *"Usar o seguinte endereço de IP"* e coloquei lá o ip público.

Após isso, eu não conseguia mais me conectar em lugar nenhum, não conseguia abrir sites e nem nada do tipo (pelo que eu me lembre, ele falava que era uma falha no DNS ou algo do tipo) e precisei restaurar as configurações do sistema pois, desfazer as alterações que eu fiz não funcionava. Eu fiz algo de errado ? Para eu utilizar o IP público eu preciso falar com o provedor ou algo do tipo ?

Falei com um amigo meu, e ele me recomendou tentar utilizar o Hamachi. Então ao criar o servidor, eu passava o ipv4 do hamachi assim como eu faço quando vou jogar Minecraft com um amigo em LAN. Porém, nem mesmo com hamachi eu conseguia me conectar numa outra rede.

Alguém aí que for experiente em rede pode me dizer passo a passo do que fazer para se conectar de alguma forma em outra rede utilizando o IP ? E já aproveitando, qual é o Port number correto para usar ? Estou utilizando port number 60 ou 80.

Comment: Alguém me ajuda por favor!

Comment: Provavelmente ja tenha encontrado o problema, mas quando for usar alguma porta, aconselho que utilize uma numero de porta alta e verifique se não há outras aplicações que estejam utilizando a mesma porta, a porta 80 é usado para http por padrão, o seu modem contem ambos os ips, __publico__ e __privado__, o seu pc utiliza a rede interna da sua casa que seria a lan e quem faz a comunicação pra rede publica é o seu modem, ja tentou redirecionar as portas na configuração dele? pesquise __port forward__

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você tem que estudar redes. Entender sobre NAT - e aí sim, depois que entender o que está fazendo, ou usar um produto como o Hamachi, ou configurar seu roteador em casa, de forma que algumas das portas do seu IP público sejam roteadas para o seu computador.

Aqui pode ter um pouco de informação para esclarecer:

http://blog.ccna.com.br/2009/04/19/entendendo-nat-network-address-translation/

A maior parte dos provedores de internet no Brasil hoje deixam instruções de como acessar seu roteador, de forma que você consiga fazer essa configuração.

Mas mesmo assim, devido a escasses de IP V4 atual, nada garante que seu provedor te de um IP v4 real até o seu roteador - pode ser que dentro do provedor mesmo você esteja atrás de outra camada de NAT - se for o caso, só algo do tipo do Hamachi mesmo.

Basicamente o que acontece: o seu provedor te entrega um endereço de IP público, que é o endereço que o *roteador* da sua casa_ usa para acessar a internet. Nos modelos antigos, do tempo da internet discada, e mesmo nas primeiras banda-larga, em que havia apenas um computador da casa ligado à internet, esse IP também podia ser o IP do computador.

No roteador da sua casa ficam as configurações da rede local (LAN) - que usam endereços privados - esses se caracterizam por serem endereços em algumas faixas pré-fixadas de IPs do tipo: "192.168.0.XXX" - qualquer dispositivo dentro da rede da sua casa que você tente configurar manualmente para um IP de fora dessa faixa, obviamente não vai funcionar. Não adiante você colocar o seu computador para responder ao mesmo IP que seu roteador responde da sua casa para a internet - todos os dispositivos: roteador, computadores, celulares, smart-tvs, na sua casa só conseguem trocar informações diretamente usando a faixa de IPs locais - um IP de fora dessa faixa não tem como ser roteado e não vai conseguir falar com ninguém.

O "modem" de internet, em geral faz também as vezes de wifi, e é o "gateway" - ele pode ser acessado por um endereço fixo, e em geral tem uma interface WEB para configuração. Basta olhar o campo "gateway" da configuração de rede (quando estiver funcionando, com as configurações padrão) do seu computador para saber qual é, mas quase sempre é o endereço terminado em "1" dentro da rede local. Para o exemplo acima, seria "192.168.0.1" .  Nesse caso, aponte seu navegador para o endereço "http://192.168.0.1" e você deve ver a interface WEB do seu roteador wifi.

Consulte a documentação que o seu provedor deixou com você, ou entre em contato com o suporte, para ver as credenciais de acesso ao seu modem/wifi. Até há alguns anos, a maior parte dos provedores deixava a senha padrão do equipamento. De um tempo para cá, cada roteador tem um login e senhas personalizados, que em geral ficam afixados em uma etiqueta no próprio roteador.

Essa interface web vai variar de equipamento para equipamento e de versão para versão - mas todas tem as mesmas funcionalidades - entre elas a de "roteamento": você pode configurar manualmente uma porta do seu IP público, que é o roteador que "responde" para ser encaminhada (forwarded) para um IP e porta da rede local internos. Pronto - isso é tudo o que você tem que fazer: o seu computador pode responer no IP 192.168.0.11 porta 8000 para um pacote que chegar no seu IP p[iblico, porta 80. = é só voce configurar esse encaminhamento no roteador.

Como coloquei acima, isso vai funcionar, a não ser que você esteja  atrás de mais uma camada de NAT do provedor - ou seja: se o seu IP do roteador for de fato público. Caso contrário, espero ter explicado os conceitos com outras palavras de forma que você possa entender como usar o Hamashi para o que deseja.

Comment: Eu entendi mais ou menos do que você falou, mas ainda assim, já ajudou um pouquinho a chegar na solução. Como você falou, vou estudar redes para entender melhor tudo isso, mas é possível você explicar na resposta como funciona o Hamachi para eu entender o porquê eu não conseguia me conectar com ele? Obrigado!